# How can I display 2 big buttons next to each other html & css

Tags: html, css

I'm new to html and css and I'm trying to make a webpage.
I created 2 big buttons, each about half the size of the screen. The problem is I can't display them next to each other. Instead they are displayed one above the other.

The little piece of html is below the css of the added snippet which probably looks a bit messy.

**EDIT**: the idea is to create a page divided in 2 like --> http://www.masitupungato.com/ <-- but a very basic look

Here are the screenshots:

[image: Button supposed to be on the left side]
[image: Button supposed to be on the right side]

```css
body {
 background: #191B1C;
 color: white;
 font-family: helvetica;
}

ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

li a{
 color: white;
 background: #2A2F30;
 height: 616px;
 width: 650px;
 border-radius: 40px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 100px;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-decoration: none; 
 padding-top: 400px; 
 display: inline-block;
}

li a:hover{
 background: #2FA2C4;
 border: 4px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <ul>
  <li id="left-container"><a href="#">Browse</a></li>
  <li id="right-container"><a href="#">Upload</a></li>
 </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Woah those are some big buttons you got there. You just need to add display: inline-block to your li element.

Comment: Here's a website that has different resources. It might help you speed up your front-end learning curve [**Resource Cards**](https://resourcecards.com/free-front-end-resources/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add style for `ul li`

```
ul li {
    float:left; //or display:inline-block;
}
```

```css
body {
 background: #191B1C;
 color: white;
 font-family: helvetica;
}

ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  float:left
}

li a {
 color: white;
 background: #2A2F30;
 height: 616px;
 width: 650px;
 border-radius: 40px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 100px;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-decoration: none; 
 padding-top: 400px; 
 display: inline-block;
}

li a:hover{
 background: #2FA2C4;
 border: 4px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <ul>
  <li id="left-container"><a href="#">Browse</a></li>
  <li id="right-container"><a href="#">Upload</a></li>
 </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use display: table-cell; on the li items.

```
li {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9627av37/1/

Answer (score 0):

simple display:flex; should do it.

```css
body {
 background: #191B1C;
 color: white;
 font-family: helvetica;
}

ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
    display: flex;
}

li a{
 color: white;
 background: #2A2F30;
    display-inline:block;
 height: 616px;
 width: 650px;
 border-radius: 40px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 100px;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-decoration: none; 
 padding-top: 400px; 
 display: inline-block;
}

li a:hover{
 background: #2FA2C4;
 border: 4px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <ul>
  <li id="left-container"><a href="#">Browse</a></li>
  <li id="right-container"><a href="#">Upload</a></li>
 </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
 background: #191B1C;
 color: white;
 font-family: helvetica;
}

ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
li { display: inline-block;}

li a{
 color: white;
 background: #2A2F30;
 height: 616px;
 width: 650px;
 border-radius: 40px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 100px;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-decoration: none; 
 padding-top: 400px; 
 display: inline-block;
}

li a:hover{
 background: #2FA2C4;
 border: 4px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <ul>
  <li id="left-container"><a href="#">Browse</a></li>
  <li id="right-container"><a href="#">Upload</a></li>
 </ul>

</div>
```

Just add `li { display: inline-block; }` to the CSS and pray users have a window that wide.

Comment: I tried using 50% instead of 650px but nothing happened.. no background. It's only my second day in css :s

Answer (score 0):

You can use table with 50% width for each td and get the button inside of them like

```
<table width="100%" border="1">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td width="50%" align="center"><button>first</button></td>
         <td width="50%" align="center"><button>second</button></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Although this is not the best case, but you can use for your thing, best would be using bootstrap and other libraries that gives you grid system to do this.

Please look in those libraries too.

Comment: Thank you, I will.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the quick answers guys. Both solutions worked.
If i use `ul li {float: left;}` the footer (wich i didnt insert in my snippet here) pops up but thats not a problem.

I had tried `float: left;` by writing it in my div **class** wich didnt work.
Anyway, thanks :)